# Spring: DTO file size validation

Tags: java, spring, validation, multipart, dto

Consider two controller endpoint methods:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

  @PostMapping("/foo")
  public ResponseEntity<?> foo(@Valid @RequestBody FooDto dto) {
    // ..
  }

  @PostMapping("/bar")
  public ResponseEntity<?> bar(@Valid @RequestBody BarDto dto) {
    // ..
  }
}
```

Actual dtos contain the multipart object, and are defined as:

```
class FooDto {

  @NotNull
  private MultipartFile file;

  @Size(min 2, max 40)
  private String name;
}
```

and similarly for `BarDto` of course.

---

Currently, the max file size is defined globally in Spring properties as:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
```

In an ideal scenario, I want to control each individual dto max file size from the properties, e.g. as:

```
foo-dto.max-size=10MB
bar-dto.max-size=500MB
```

In a less idea scenario, I would like to control the size from the inside of the dto classes, e.g.:

```
class BarDto {

  @FileSize(max = '500MB') // <-- something like this
  @NotNull
  private MultipartFile file;

  // ..
}
```

**Any tips on how can I achieve that? Are there existing annotations for file validation, compatible with Spring?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own annotation for example `SizeConstraint` and `Validator` by `implementing` `ConstraintValidator<SizeConstraint, String>`. There you can validate any parameters including the size of MultiPartFile

see moree [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator)

Comment: I'm afraid it won't prevent huge file uploads before the constraint check gets performed.

Comment: Perhaps the servlet file check could be turned off globally (unlimited file size allowed), so then I could rely on custom validators?

Comment: custom validation is a normal solution. All the validators default and custom will create as Spring bean. Try to check the performance by JMH before and after. I'll very surprised if there be significant differences

Comment: @weno Nope, by default files uploaded within POSTs are **first** saved at the local file system, and only then Spring MVC delegates the check to the validators. Having that in mind, consider your global limit is set to 1GB, but the particular constraint is set to 1Mb, but the user attempts uploading a 1GB file: 999MB of the data will be rejected and stay at your file system for certain amount of time (taking much time to upload, of course).

Comment: Take a look at `org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver` and `org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload`: I had to extend two of these in one of my previous projects to track content length on-fly preventing huge payloads and rejecting for example invalid files (e.g., a user is allowed to upload JPEGs only but attempting to upload a text file). I don't really recall how they both work together, but this might be the key.

Comment: good point above